# Implicit declaration of function error when installing a network driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I am trying to **install this NIC** on **Ubuntu Desktop** 14.04.3 LTS (fresh install, just formatted):

[Silicom PXG6BPi Six Port Copper Gigabit Ethernet PCI-X Bypass Server Adapter](http://www.silicom-usa.com/Networking_Bypass_Adapters/PXG6BPi-Six_Port_Copper_Gigabit_Ethernet_PCI-X_Bypass_Server_Adapter_Intel_based_58)

According to its **docs**:

> 1. Move the base driver tar file to the directory of your choice.  For    example, use /home/username/e1000bp or /usr/local/src/e1000bp.
> 2. Untar/unzip archive:
>
>    tar zxf e1000bp-x.x.x.tar.gz
> 3. Change to the driver src directory:
>
>    cd e1000bp-x.x.x/src/
> 4. Compile the driver module:
>
>    make install

But I get some `implicit declaration of function` error:

```
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ sudo make install make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-57-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_ethtool.o
/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_ethtool.c: In function ‘e1000_set_ethtool_ops’:
/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_ethtool.c:1930:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SET_ETHTOOL_OPS’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     SET_ETHTOOL_OPS(netdev, &e1000_ethtool_ops);
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_ethtool.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic»
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I think all the possibly needed stuff (`linux-generic`, `make`, `gcc`, and even `ethtool`) is installed (my Ubuntu is in spanish, sorry):

```
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ sudo apt-get install ethtool linux-generic make gcc
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
ethtool ya está en su versión más reciente.
fijado ethtool como instalado manualmente.
gcc ya está en su versión más reciente.
make ya está en su versión más reciente.
fijado make como instalado manualmente.
linux-generic ya está en su versión más reciente.
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  linux-headers-3.16.0-55 linux-headers-3.16.0-55-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-55-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-55-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

And this is the `/src` directory listing:

```
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ ls -la
total 1352
drwxr-xr-x 3 luis luis   4096 ene  5 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 luis luis   4096 jul 15  2014 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis   5653 dic 22  2008 bp_ioctl.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  91521 sep 19  2012 bypass.c
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  14501 dic 19  2011 bypass.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51576 ene  5 05:38 bypass.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48684 ene  5 05:38 .bypass.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  62552 jul 15  2014 e1000_ethtool.c
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  11577 jul 15  2014 e1000.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 192747 jul 15  2014 e1000_hw.c
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 143287 jul 15  2014 e1000_hw.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110576 ene  5 05:38 e1000_hw.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48706 ene  5 05:38 .e1000_hw.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 153304 jul 15  2014 e1000_main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81472 ene  5 05:38 e1000_main.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  49206 ene  5 05:38 .e1000_main.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis   3967 sep 19  2012 e1000_osdep.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  22838 jul 15  2014 e1000_param.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27840 ene  5 05:38 e1000_param.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48739 ene  5 05:38 .e1000_param.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  59214 jul 15  2014 e1000_proc.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51128 ene  5 05:38 e1000_proc.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48771 ene  5 05:38 .e1000_proc.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  11317 jul 15  2014 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 ene  5 05:38 .tmp_versions
```

This is my Ubuntu Desktop version:

```
luis@Terminus:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

An important detail: this same procedure **works** perfect on **Ubuntu Server** v14.04.1 LTS (same computer, on another partition):

```
luis@ThreepWood:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_main.o
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_param.o
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_hw.o
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_proc.o
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/bypass.o
  CC [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000_ethtool.o
  LD [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000bp.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000bp.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/luis/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src/e1000bp.ko
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic»
gzip -c ../e1000bp.7 > e1000bp.7.gz
# remove all old versions of the driver
find /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic -name e1000bp.ko -exec rm -f {} \; || true
find /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic -name e1000bp.ko.gz -exec rm -f {} \; || true
install -D -m 644 e1000bp.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000bp/e1000bp.ko
/sbin/depmod -a || true
install -D -m 644 e1000bp.7.gz /usr/share/man/man7/e1000bp.7.gz
man -c -P'cat > /dev/null' e1000bp || true
e1000bp.
luis@ThreepWood:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$
```

In this case, it is too a **fresh install**, but not up to date (only installed `make` and `gcc`, as `ethtool` was already included):

```
luis@ThreepWood:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

And this is the `/src` directory after compilation:

```
luis@ThreepWood:~/Temporal/PXG6BPi/e1000bp-7.3.21-k8.silc.6.1/src$ ls -la
total 2216
drwxr-xr-x 3 luis luis   4096 ene  5 18:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 luis luis   4096 jul 15  2014 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis   5653 dic 22  2008 bp_ioctl.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  91521 sep 19  2012 bypass.c
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  14501 dic 19  2011 bypass.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52088 ene  5 18:26 bypass.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55509 ene  5 18:26 .bypass.o.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4942 ene  5 18:26 e1000bp.7.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 343160 ene  5 18:26 e1000bp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    394 ene  5 18:26 .e1000bp.ko.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9288 ene  5 18:26 e1000bp.mod.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12912 ene  5 18:26 e1000bp.mod.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29999 ene  5 18:26 .e1000bp.mod.o.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 331102 ene  5 18:26 e1000bp.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    601 ene  5 18:26 .e1000bp.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  62552 jul 15  2014 e1000_ethtool.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31432 ene  5 18:26 e1000_ethtool.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55586 ene  5 18:26 .e1000_ethtool.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  11577 jul 15  2014 e1000.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 192747 jul 15  2014 e1000_hw.c
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 143287 jul 15  2014 e1000_hw.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110576 ene  5 18:26 e1000_hw.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55531 ene  5 18:26 .e1000_hw.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis 153304 jul 15  2014 e1000_main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81776 ene  5 18:26 e1000_main.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56081 ene  5 18:26 .e1000_main.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis   3967 sep 19  2012 e1000_osdep.h
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  22838 jul 15  2014 e1000_param.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27840 ene  5 18:26 e1000_param.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55564 ene  5 18:26 .e1000_param.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  59214 jul 15  2014 e1000_proc.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  50464 ene  5 18:26 e1000_proc.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55596 ene  5 18:26 .e1000_proc.o.cmd
-rwxr--r-- 1 luis luis  11317 jul 15  2014 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     77 ene  5 18:26 modules.order
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 ene  5 18:26 Module.symvers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 ene  5 18:26 .tmp_versions
```

I think I understand the basics of this kind of `[error][2]` but I don't know how to apply it to this particular case.

**Why** is this happening?
How could I **solve** this error and install/compile the drivers?
Maybe just copying the `/src` directory? The docs say :

> The binary will be installed as:
>
> ```
>  /lib/modules/<KERNEL VERSION>/kernel/drivers/net/e1000bp/e1000bp.[k]o
> ```
>
> The install locations listed above are the default locations.  They
>   might not be correct for certain Linux distributions.

Comment: `#define SET_ETHTOOL_OPS(netdev,ops) ( (netdev)->ethtool_ops = (ops) )` was removed in kernel 3.16. You can define it yourself, but a driver written prior to the release of 3.16 may fail in other ways.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I contacted the reseller of the NIC, and they are not planning to release updated drivers, as they say this card is too old. There is no chance, then?

Comment: If you don't really need kernel 3.16, you could downgrade to 3.13, which you said was OK with the driver.